# Looping through a specified array?

Tags: vba, excel, row

I am trying to match the row height of specific rows from one sheet to another, This works if I just remove all lines with rowlist and do For i = 1 to 200, but this takes too long. I only want to match a few row heights and not go through all between 1 and 200. My code is below:

```
Dim y As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim rowlist() As Variant

rowlist = Array(3, 5, 23, 30)

For i = LBound(rowlist) To UBound(rowlist)

y = Worksheets("Development").Rows(i).RowHeight
Worksheets("Final").Rows(i).RowHeight = y

Next i
```

Comment: replace both Rows(i) with Rows(rowlist(i))?

Comment: Works, but can't up vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're setting and using `y`, use `.Rows(rowlist(i))` rather than `.Rows(i)`.

`i` simply stores the **index** of the array, not the value, i.e.

- i = 0 ; rowlist(i) =3
- i = 1 ; rowlist(i)= 5
- i = 2 ; rowlist(i)= 23
- i = 3 ; rowlist(i)= 30

So you're correct in looping from `LBound(rowlist)` to `UBound(rowlist)`, you just need to make sure that you're using the values stored in the array within that loop.